# How to select n number of lines in GVIM

Tags: vim, editor

I am using gvim as my text editor on linux server.
I have a large file, some 10K lines.

I need to select `n` number of lines; e.g., lines `512` to `1034` and replace them with another lines. How can I achieve this?

Comment: How are you getting these other lines?

Comment: I am doing simple copy paste , but as I need to select a big part of file , its taking too much of time , is there any way I can select lines using some commnad so that I can replace that with the matter I want.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the other lines are in a file you could do the following.

```
:512,1034d | r <filename>
```

`512,1034` specifies a range from line 512 to 1034.
`d` deletes the line

After the lines are removed you place the content of `<filename>` at line 512 with `r` or `read`

---

If the contents are in the `"` register (as if you yanked the contents) you could use

```
:512,1034p
```

to replace those lines with the contents of the `"` register.

Answer (score 1):

Select a particular line and use the `nj` command where `n` is the number of lines u want to jump.